# Regular expression for Arabic letters on android

Tags: android, regex

here is my code and it's not working, always return false

```
private boolean validate_arabic() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = joinNameEditText.getText().toString();

    String NamePattern = "[\u0600-\u06FF]";
    if (name.matches(NamePattern))
    return true;
    else 
        return false ;
}
```

Comment: Use

    String NamePattern = "[\\u0600-\\u06FF]+";

Comment: Couldn’t the `if-else` logic down there be reduced to `return name.matches(NamePattern);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex checks if the name is exactly one character with a unicode value between 0x0600 and 0x06FF.  Try `[\\u0600-\\u06FF]+` if you want to test if your input consists soley of one or more Arabic characters.

EDIT: Also need to escape the backspace character.